# Using the peer node across multiple networks in hyperledger fabric 1.4.4

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am currently having a hyperledger network (**Network1**) with a consortium of 5 organisations (*A , B , C , D , E*) supporting a use case. I want to support another use case with 3 organisations from network1 (*A, B , C*) and two other organisations (*P , Q*) not present in Network1. So I thought of creating another network (**Network2**) with a new consortium of these 5 members. I already have 2 peers per organisation in Network1.

**Is it possible to reuse the same peers of 3 orgs (*A , B , C*) in the Network2 ?**.

Some of the questions I had to myself were :

1. How does the peer separate the data between the two networks ? - I have explored the way the ledger data gets stored in the peer nodes , peers nodes store the data as a block file for each channel in the chains directory of the ledgerdata folder. I could not see any kind of separation of the data at the network level in the peers folder structure , so if I create the another channel in Network2 that matches a channel name in Network1 , there would be an issue.
2. Will the communication between the organisations peers using grpc have any issue , when the same peer is shared across multiple networks ?

Is sharing the same peer across networks a correct go forward ?
What would be the alternatives to prevent creating separate peer nodes for a single organisation across multiple networks (Use cases) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fabric does not really have the concept of a network per se.  Peers can join multiple channels and each of those channels can be managed by a separate ordering service.  The caveat here (as you correctly mention above) is that a peer cannot join two channels with the same name even if each of the channels is managed by a different ordering service.